# "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Good Day everyone. I'm developing a Cross Platform Application in Xamarin.Forms when I encounter this error "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference". My project is working fine before I install a Nuget package (Circle Image View in Xamarin), but when I uninstall it (without changing a single line of code) the said error started to appear.
I tried to Build, Rebuild it but still it does not work. Anything I can do to fix this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

These are the errors:

**Error 1:**

> The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Error 2:**

> The type or namespace name 'Application' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Error 3:**

> The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Error 4:**

> The type or namespace name 'ContentPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: We might need a bit more to go on. Like, which nuget package for starters?

Comment: Also, the *complete* error message would help.

Comment: @ojf I installed Circle Image View in xamarin.

Comment: You installed it, changed nothing, then uninstalled it?

Comment: try mo close visual studio then rebuild uli your packages are messed up

Comment: @ojf Yes sir because when I installed the Nuget, that error came out. Hoping the error will be gone, I uninstalled it. But nothing happened.

Comment: @Katana I already did that but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 21):

When I got an error like this on my Environment, I do following:

1. Clean solution in VisualStudio
2. Close VisualStudio
3. Delete all "bin" and "obj" Folders (from the whole solution) manually
4. Delete "packages" Folder manually
5. Restart VisualStudio
6. Rebuild all

In most cases, this solves this reference-problems (in my case)

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is having issues like this. This solution fixed for me. Thanks

Comment: By today, it is still an issue that can be solved this way. I use Visual Studio 2017, too, and it worked for me as well.

Comment: This solution fixed my problem too! I thought that the project was lost because of all the missing references. Doing this fixed all references! :) Thank you!

Comment: Where is the packages folder? Can you please add that explanation.

Comment: @AnupBuchke It depends on how you setup your nuget-configuration. By default, there should be a packages folder in the same folder, where your solution-file '.sln' is saved. (Maybe you can check this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)

Comment: Thanks. Deleting packages folder worked for me

Answer (score 3):

- Right click on the referenced project -> Unload Project
- Right click on the referenced project -> Edit ...
- Add a space after any line in the file
- Save
- Right click on the referenced project -> Reload Project

Answer (score 1):

What is the nuget package that you uninstall? Are you sure you aren't using anywhere in the code. If there are any references to it you will get this error.

For example if you have:

```
using Ninject;
```

And then you uninstall ninject you would get this error.

Comment: I installed Circle Image View Sir. Yes I'm sure I don't have error in my code before I installed that.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and my problem was that I compiled my dll to a newer .net framework version than the project that I was adding the reference to.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it helped to add this line to my *.csproj:

```
<Reference Include="...">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as deletion of `bin` and `packages` folders manually, deleting the respective error from the `test.Android.csproj` file worked for me. The error was

> this project references nuget package(s) that are missing on this computer

Answer (score 0):

I just quit Visual Studio and started it again. The error was gone!

Answer (score -1):

My case was very weird. I suddenly started getting this for just one file for no reason at all.

After deleting and retyping the `using` directives, the error was gone.