# This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer - Android.Support.Annotations.targets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, telerik

Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.26.1.0.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets.

Comment: try solution level package restore

Comment: Try to clean all references: Check my answer on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37698515/2653134